# Placing multiple outputs from each function call using apply into a row in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a function that I repeat, changing the argument each time, using apply/sapply/lapply.

Works great.

I want to return a data set, where each row contains two (or more) variables from each iteration of the function.

Instead I get an unusable list.

```
do <-function(x){
  a <- x+1
  b <- x+2
  cbind(a,b)
}

over <- [1:6]

final <- lapply(over, do)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your function `do`, you can use `sapply` and transpose it.

```
data.frame(t(sapply(over, do)))

#  X1 X2
#1  2  3
#2  3  4
#3  4  5
#4  5  6
#5  6  7
#6  7  8
```

If you want to use `do` in current form with `lapply`, we can do

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(over, do))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```r
as.data.frame(Reduce(rbind, final))
#   a b
# 1 2 3
# 2 3 4
# 3 4 5
# 4 5 6
# 5 6 7
# 6 7 8
```

See `?Reduce` and `?rbind` for information about what they'll do. 
You could also modify your `final` expression as

```r
final <- as.data.frame(Reduce(rbind, lapply(over, do)))
#final
#   a b
# 1 2 3
# 2 3 4
# 3 4 5
# 4 5 6
# 5 6 7
# 6 7 8
```